# GoogleSheet best 5 results with a maximum in another column

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking for a formula or something similar to output 5 best results.

The table looks like this.

| Name | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 4 | 0 |
| b | 29 | 28 |
| c | 30 | 32 |
| d | 26 | 26 |
| e | 16 | 14 |
| f | 40 | 42 |
| g | 10 | 16 |
| h | 2 | 0 |

much more data

Column B may not exceed a total of 100 for 5 results.
The maximum with 5 results from column C need to be determined.
The 5 best names should be displayed.

I hope you understand my problem.
Thanks!

I tried with LARGE function but failed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you ask a question like this, please include what the expected output is, and the code you’ve tried.

Comment: thanks!
The result should be 

f 40 42
g 10 16
z 22 45
ac 18 15
az 10 16 

I tried LARGE and SORTN but have not managed the dependency of max 100 points.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RE-EDIT:
In order to filter when C is greater than B I wrapped it in LAMBDA not to repeat lots of times the same filter:

```
=LAMBDA(filtered;QUERY({SEQUENCE(ROWS(filtered))\filtered};"SELECT Col2,Col3,Col4 WHERE Col1 >= "& MATCH(1;MAP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(filtered));LAMBDA(c;IF(SUM(QUERY({SEQUENCE(ROWS(filtered))\filtered};"Select Col3 Where Col1 >= "&c&" limit "&J2))>100;0;1)));0)&" limit "&J2))(FILTER(SORT(A2:C;3;0);A2:A<>0;B2:B<C2:C))
```

---

You can try with this, with MATCH & MAP I find the index of the first 5 numbers that don't sum more than 100, and the SEQUENCE let me filter it in the QUERY:

```
=QUERY({SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A)),FILTER(SORT(A2:C,3,0),A2:A<>0)},"SELECT Col2,Col3,Col4 WHERE Col1 >= "& MATCH(1,MAP(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A)),LAMBDA(c,IF(SOMME(QUERY({SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:C)),SORT(A2:C,3,0)},"Select Col3 Where Col1 >= "&c&" limit 5"))>100,0,1))),0)&" limit 5")
```

EDIT: Locale "translation"

```
=QUERY({SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A))\FILTER(SORT(A2:C;3;0);A2:A<>0)};"SELECT Col2,Col3,Col4 WHERE Col1 >= "& MATCH(1;MAP(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A2:A));LAMBDA(c;IF(SUM(QUERY({SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:C))\SORT(A2:C;3;0)};"Select Col3 Where Col1 >= "&c&" limit 5"))>100;0;1)));0)&" limit 5")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I have expressed myself in an unfortunate way.
All 5 names may have a maximum total value of 100.
So the formula have to check if the first 5 have <=100. If no, then search further.

Comment: Try the new update

Comment: Thanks again, got an error if i insert the formula.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11GKsReT3QbsqDtbnnlRI4yBcWTMd0ggnc41cGrl1zJk/edit?usp=sharing

Link with the file and data

Comment: Ohhh, it was a thing with the "translation" of the comma with your locale settings. `,` was changed to `;` but when working with arrays it should have been changed to "\".  A little "bug" from Sheets, I updated the post with a version that will work for your region and a screenshot

Comment: Works so far, but the value of column C is not the highest. 
However, it should be. I have probably expressed myself wrong again.
It should practically determine the highest value in column C but not exceed the value 100 in column B with 5 players.

Maybe it is not possible with Sheets.

Comment: Those are the highest consecutive 5 values in C that don't sum more than 100 in B. I don't think there is a way to find it with non consecutive values only with formula, with code yes. But which are the highest values that fit yourr needs?, The highest possible sum in C?, The highest first possible value in C? Or which?

Comment: Works well with less than 5.

Is there a way to make the limit "5" dynamic?
Tried it with '"&$j$2&"' but unfortunately that does not work

Comment: I changed it in your spreadsheet. You should change both times there is a limit and not use the single quotation marks since they're numbers not strings ;)

Comment: You are great thanks!One last thing is it possible to take only players where the value in column C is greater than in column B?

Comment: Updated in the answer and your spreadsheet!